# Typewriter Effect: Caret is going way too far

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a normal typewriter effect on my text. But the caret is going far more than the text actually is.

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrzSr.png)

My code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="title">
   <h1>Hi, I'm ConnerDE</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.title h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    animation: typing 3.5s steps(16, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0
    }
    to {
        width: 100%
    }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
    from,
    to {
        border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
        border-color: orange
    }
}
```

The caret should end directly at the end of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the title element instead and adjust its width like below:

```css
.title {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: fit-content;
}
.title h1 {
   color: #000;
   font-family: monospace;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-right: .15em solid orange;
   white-space: nowrap;
   letter-spacing: .15em;
   animation: typing 3.5s steps(16, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0
    }
    to {
        width: 100%
    }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
    from,
    to {
        border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
        border-color: orange
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
   <h1>Hi, I'm ConnerDE</h1>
</div>
```

And if you want the moving effect you can center the text as well:

```css
.title {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: fit-content;
}
.title h1 {
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #000;
   font-family: monospace;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-right: .15em solid orange;
   white-space: nowrap;
   letter-spacing: .15em;
   animation: typing 3.5s steps(16, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0
    }
    to {
        width: 100%
    }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
    from,
    to {
        border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
        border-color: orange
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
   <h1>Hi, I'm ConnerDE</h1>
</div>
```